# Use variable in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to make a dynamic class within my model, a simple explanation of what I'm wanting is below.

I have a model called 'feed' which has a 'url' field within each entry, I'm trying to make a class within my model call the corresponding URL to each feed entry.

> e.g. The feed entry 'lolcats' would call the url 'www.lolcats.com'
>   within the class

Below is the current class I have within the feed.rb model

```
  def boom
    response = self.class.get("/tVv8nTahbhgkyIUW8ByCe0-7/last_ready_run/data?&format=json")
    @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]
    @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }
  end
```

It works perfectly and displays all the data but obviously very static and clunky - as I don't want to start adding individual classes for each feed I want to call.

On my view I have

```
<% @boom.each do |img| %>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <%= image_tag(img) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I just don't have a clue how to do it, any help would be brilliant!

Comment: Does each feed need special handling? If so, it's not always a bad idea to break out that into different classes and use dependency injection to mix them in.

Comment: Most feeds have the same properties and the same JSON response

Comment: Maybe some kind of mapping table is required where you match feed to handler with a safe default for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to start adding individual classes for each feed I want to call.

I think you mean individual ***methods***.

You could pass in the URL, but I gather that you don't want to pass `/tVv8nTahbhgkyIUW8ByCe0-7/last_ready_run/data?&format=json` as a param, with good reason.

You mentioned mapping, so I *think* what you want is a class constant:

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  FEEDS = { ready_run:'/tVv8nTahbhgkyIUW8ByCe0-7/last_ready_run/data?&format=json',
           other_feed:'....',
           ... }

  def boom_for feed
    response = self.class.get(FEEDS[feed])
    @elements = response.parsed_response["image"]
    @parsed = @elements.collect { |e| e['url'] }
  end
```

To use it,

```
boom_for :ready_run
```

> I'm trying to make a class within my model call the corresponding URL to each feed entry.

I think you mean make a ***method***.